# select rownumber in xquery and convert it to sql rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

i have a table which i save user's search result rows in xml format as follows :

```
<row id="5083" />
<row id="5085" />
<row id="5087" />
<row id="5090" />
<row id="5094" />
... (about 500,000 rows)
```

where each row element contains id of the result record which will be shown in result page.
now i need to select ids of one specific page for example page 2 ( 10th element to 20th element )

the first problem is how can i get that result in xquery ?
i tried to use position() function but it didn't work ...

```
select @results.query('for $x in (row)
where $x/position() > 10
return ($x)')
```

and the second prblem is how can get my result ids as sql rows instead of xmlnodelist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [nodes() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to shred your XML and use the [value() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract the value for attribute `id`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1771)

**Query 1**:

```
declare @results xml = '
<row id="5083" />
<row id="5085" />
<row id="5087" />
<row id="5090" />
<row id="5094" />'

select T.N.value('@id', 'int') as id
from @results.nodes('row[position() >= 2 and position() < 4]') as T(N)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1771/0)**:

```
|   ID |
--------
| 5085 |
| 5087 |
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
for $x in (row) where $x/position() > 10 return ($x)
```

$x iterates over all the row children after the 10th but for each returns a sequence of length 1 with just one row element so $x/position() is always 1.

You could use

```
row[position() >=10 and position() < 20]
```

which will return elements in positions 10 to 19.  If you want just the id's rather than the element nodes then

```
row[position() >=10 and position() < 20]/string(@id)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ... it helped a lot ... but the string function got an exception : XQuery [query()]: The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.

Comment: you must be using a non standard or broken xquery engine then, but probably you can just omit the string() function in this case and use `/@id` at the end.